# How to compare 2 cards in a JavaScript card game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a game with JavaScript that randomly selects 52 random cards (no jokers) and displays the cards one at a time while comparing the cards depending on the card being lower than the last card that was selected.

So, it's a high and low card game.

Here is my code:

**CSS**

```
body {
    border: 2px solid #f45f;      
}
div {
    background:red;    
}
#card {
    font-size:40px;
    background:red;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var cards = [
["&spades;","&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;","&spades;","&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;","&spades;","&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;","&spades;","&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;",
"&spades;","&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;","&spades;","&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;","&spades;","&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;","&spades;","&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;",
"&spades;","&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;","&spades;","&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;","&spades;","&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;","&spades;","&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;",
"&spades;","&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;"],
[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13]

];

var x=0;
var newCard=[],[];
function Start(){
    document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML ="<br>Welcome to the high and low card game ! :)";

    document.getElementById("test").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("test2").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("test1").style.display = 'none';    
}

function highOrLow(answer){
    var answer=answer;
    var rand=Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
    document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML =rand;
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML =x;
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "Is The next card higher or lower ?";
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = answer;

    document.getElementById("card").innerHTML = cards[1][rand]+cards[0][rand];

    if (x < 51) {
        return x++;
    }
    else if (x = 51) {
        document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML ="";
        document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML ="";
        document.getElementById("res").innerHTML ="";
        document.getElementById("card").innerHTML ="";
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("test").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("test2").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("test").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("test2").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("test1").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "the game is over";

        return x = 0;
    }    
}   

function clbutton() {
    document.getElementById("test").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("test2").style.display = 'none';    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body onload="clbutton()">
    <div id="top">
        <center><h1>High Low Card Game</h1></center>
    </div>
    <br>
    <p>the rules are simple chose if the next card is high or is the card low and try to beat your own score !
    &spades;        
    &clubs;     
    &diams;     
    &hearts;
    </p>
    <br>    

    <button id="test1" type="button"
    onclick="setTimeout( Start(), 1000000 )">
    Start Game</button> 

    <span id="welcome"></span>
    <p id="name"></p>
    <p id="res"></p>
    <br>
    <p id="res1"></p>
    <br>
    <span id="card"></span>

    <br>

    <span id="question"></span>

    <button id="test" type="button"
    onclick="highOrLow('high')" >
    Higher</button>
    <br>
    <button id="test2" type="button"
    onclick="highOrLow('low')">
    Lower</button>    

    <br>

    <span id="high"></span>
</body>
```

Comment: So, what is the issue?  You will need to be more specific. There are a few problems with your code that I see at first glance. For example, you use the assignment operator (`=`) rather than the equality operator (`===`) here: `if (x = 51)` which I suspect is not your intention.

Comment: Please check what a [mcve] is. You do not specify any issue and your code is not minimal.

Comment: the problem is how do i compare a new card to an old selected card ?

Comment: @benji8 I have added comparison logic in my answer

Comment: you did thanks . i didn't see it until now

Comment: Your question inspired me to make [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ajmair01/q9bp7g60/).

Comment: omg your is way better  good job

Comment: @benji8 this is a good question but please provide a description to make anybody sees this post understand the aim of your question better.

Comment: @Willysatrionugroho   how would you describe it better ?

Comment: @AndrewMairose I just saw this . it is amazing !

Comment: @benji8 probably I would give an example pic of what I'm trying to achieve. I guess a picture is more universal than any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, get rid of `var newCard = [], [];`. It is causing a syntax error in your code and you don't use it anyway.

Next, set `display: none` in your css for your `#test` and `#test2` buttons, that way you don't have to call a function to do it in the onload of your `body`.

Your `else if` statement to end the game should be changed from `x = 51` to `x === 51`.

For comparing the cards, you need to store the last card's value in a variable. In the example below, I have called this `lastCard`. Use `var val = cards[1][rand]` to get the actual card value rather than the index in the array. Then you can compare it to the `lastCard` value. After you do the comparison, you then set `lastCard = val`, so that this round's card will be `lastCard` for the next round. I have also implemented a `score` in the example below to show you that the comparison is working.

Here is the comparison logic:

```
var val = cards[1][rand];

if (answer === 'high' && val > lastCard) {
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + (++score);
} else if (answer === 'low' && val < lastCard) {
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + (++score);
}

lastCard = val;
```

I also added a `displayVal` variable. This is used to change the displayed value to `A`, `J`, `Q` or `K` if the actual numeric value of the card is `1`, `11`, `12` or `13`. It is stored in this separate variable so that it will not affect the numerical comparison.

This should get you going in the right direction.

```js
var cards = [
  ["&spades;", "&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;", "&spades;", "&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;", "&spades;", "&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;", "&spades;", "&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;",
    "&spades;", "&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;", "&spades;", "&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;", "&spades;", "&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;", "&spades;", "&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;",
    "&spades;", "&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;", "&spades;", "&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;", "&spades;", "&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;", "&spades;", "&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;",
    "&spades;", "&clubs;", "&diams;", "&hearts;"
  ],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13]

];

var x = 0;
var lastCard = 0;
var score = 0;

function Start() {
  score = 0;
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + score;
  document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "<br>Welcome to the high and low card game ! :)";

  document.getElementById("test").style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById("test2").style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById("test1").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("score").style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "Is The next card higher or lower ?";

  highOrLow(null);
}

function highOrLow(answer) {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;

  var val = cards[1][rand];
  var suit = cards[0][rand];
  var displayVal = val;
  switch (displayVal) {
    case 1:
      displayVal = 'A';
      break;
    case 11:
      displayVal = 'J';
      break;
    case 12:
      displayVal = 'Q';
      break;
    case 13:
      displayVal = 'K';
      break;
  }

  document.getElementById("card").innerHTML = displayVal + suit;

  if (answer === 'high' && val > lastCard) {
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + (++score);
  } else if (answer === 'low' && val < lastCard) {
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + (++score);
  }

  lastCard = val;

  if (x < 51) {
    x++;
  } else if (x === 51) {
    document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("card").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("test").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("test2").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("test1").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "the game is over";

    x = 0;
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  border: 2px solid #f45f;
}
div {
  background: red;
}
#card {
  font-size: 40px;
  background: red;
}
#test,
#test2,
#score {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="top">
    <center>
      <h1>High Low Card Game</h1>
    </center>
  </div>
  <br>
  <p>the rules are simple chose if the next card is high or is the card low and try to beat your own score ! &spades; &clubs; &diams; &hearts;
  </p>
  <br>


  <button id="test1" type="button" onclick="setTimeout( Start(), 1000000 )">
    Start Game</button>


  <span id="welcome"></span>
  <p id="name"></p>
  <br>
  <span id="card"></span>

  <br>

  <span id="question"></span>
  <br>
  <span id="score"></span>

  <button id="test" type="button" onclick="highOrLow('high')">
    Higher</button>
  <br>
  <button id="test2" type="button" onclick="highOrLow('low')">
    Lower</button>


  <br>

  <span id="high"></span>

</body>
```